# Boolean modifier behaving strangely

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm trying to make a grappling hook. I have two objects in my scene, one for the "stick" and the other for the four claws, as shown below in the pictures. Each claw intersects the stick along its middle edge at the base, as in  the pictures (I don't think this should matter for the union, I just thought of pointing it out. I'm pretty much a newbie so I'm not sure).

The problem comes when I try to unite them with the boolean modifier. I put it on the stick object and set it to union, however, the preview shows only three of the four claws outlined (as well as the stick), and if I apply it, it does what it says. If I set it to difference it outlines the stick and the fourth claw for some reason, and if I set it to intersect, the stick disappears and it outlines the fourth blade.

I'd like to know why this happens and how to fix it, preferably without an overly cheeky workaround, I just want the boolean modifier to work. Thanks! (Pictures below, they're a lot, I hope it's not too clutered)
[image: Stick Object]
[image: Claws Object]
[image: Intersections, top view]
[image: Intersections on the Claws object]
[image: Union]
[image: Difference]
[image: Intersect]

*Edit*

For whomever is interested, here is the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nszm0Wxbn2X7TThB6ltSwOXgvJk4Y5kE

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but I would suggest to joint them manualy, it will have better topology for UV mapping and to working with it. Ii should be easy as the polygons are pretty much prepared for that.
If you insist on boolean could you upload the file? I would like to test it by myself.
Also if you don't want or dont need the seams to be perfect  you can just join the objects.

Comment: @Fowl thanks, I didn't know you could just join objects like that (as I said, I'm a newbie), it worked quite nicely. Also, I edited the post and put a link to the file there. Enjoy! :))

Comment: it worked for me. The problems can be in few things. 1)objects werent intersecting enought. 2)check you normals, some of them were inside out -> viewport overlays -> face orientation to find out errors. 3) object had points where there were 0 thickness in that three parts of the rod. Anyway I put the hooks more into the object and it worked.